# Map with invalid input returning the first inserted value of the map

Tags: c++, dictionary

I created a struct to hold the row/column index of a table

```
struct itemIndex {
    int row;
    int col;

    bool operator< (const itemIndex &i) const { if (this->col == i.col) return this->row < i.row; else return false; }
    bool operator== (const itemIndex &i) const { return (this->row == i.row && this->col == i.col); }
};
```

Now, I've created a map that holds the index as the key, but only indices in column 1 have created keys. But when calling a value with index having col = 0, it seems to return the first inserted index (row = 0, col = 0) and I'm not sure why. Here's the implementation of the code:

```
    itemIndex index;
    index.row = pLVDispInfo->item.iItem;
    index.col = pLVDispInfo->item.iSubItem;
    //example index.row = 5, index.col = 0
    bool found = false; 
    found = m_mSettingMap.find(index) != m_mSettingMap.end(); // returns true
    int val = m_mSettingMap[index];
```

Comment: Are you sure your `<` comparator satisfies [`Compare`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare) requirements?

Comment: Your `operator <` is wrong (when `col` are different), `std::tie` might help: `return std::tie(lhs.col, lhs.row) < std::tie(rhs.col, rhs.row);`

Comment: [Comparison functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare) for ordering requires [strict weak ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Strict_weak_orderings). You ordering operator `<` doesn't follow that.

Answer (score 0):

`bool operator< (const itemIndex &i) const { if (this->col == i.col) return this->row < i.row; else return false; }`

So if the col values match, you sub-order based on the row.  Normal enough.
But if the col doesn't match, you always return false?  I would expect to order based on `col` in that case.

Try:

```
bool operator< (const itemIndex &i) const 
{
   if (col == i.col) return row < i.row; 
   return col < i.col;
}
```